# How can I add a gradient to an image?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm retrieving images from the web (last.fm) and using them as backgrounds for the views in my iOS application.

How can I add a gradient to these images so that they are gradually darkened from top to bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CAGradientLayer` to apply this effect as a sub layer of the image view housing the image you download for each track. This way you'll only have to process the effect once and not every time the image changes.

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAGradientLayer.h>

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[gradient setFrame:myImageView.bounds];
[gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f] CGColor],
                     (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f] CGColor],
                     nil]];
[[myImageView layer] addSublayer:gradient];
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a gradient to your image with an image editor

[image: photoshop]

Comment: I hope that was a joke. Images are loaded from the server. On request on last.fm it gives us a link to the picture. You're offering me download pictures for each artist and manually make such here blackout.

Comment: no... place your own gradient image with a transparent background over the top of the server loaded image. If someone is taking the time to answer your question, there is no need too reply so rudely

Comment: This is a crutch. I think that you can do it more properly. I do not mean to be rude. I'm sorry.